# Rust map with locations?

Tags: rust

How do the locations in Rust obtained from /location correspond with the world map? What are the locations of the rad towns?

Answer (score 2):

You can enter co-ordinates here:
https://rustmap.net/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Michel I personally don't think that's applicable since the link is to an interactive service. The post could certainly be improved by adding an answer for the second question, but it answers the first one relatively well.

Comment: He can provide more info about the answer and the link itself. "Type here and you find what you are looking" is not a good answer for ArQAde. The idea is, you came here to find an answer HERE. even if the answer leads to another place, you already have an idea on how to solve your problem without leaving the site.

Comment: [There is a large and ever-growing debate on link-only answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link-only-answers)  StackExchange generally frowns on such answers, due to the reasons already laid out by @Michel.

Answer (score 0):

http://rustmapmarks.com/RustLocalizer.php

There you can find the coordinates when you mouse over the map.

http://rustmapmarks.com/maps.php?h=0QDSm4PsDJ1TI

There is a map with the most known places marked, mouse over the icons for the coordinates.